# strong param method expects to `define method_name` as `controller name`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, dry, strong-parameters

rails (5.2.2.1)
ruby 2.5.0p0

1. Parent controller of Country, State, City

```
class LocalityController < ApplicationController
  def create
    locality = model_name.new(locality_master_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if locality.save
        format.html { redirect_to locality, notice: 'Record was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def model_name
    "#{controller_name.titleize.delete(' ').singularize}".constantize
  end

  def locality_params
    @locality_params = %i|name code status|
  end

  def locality_master_params
    params.require("#{controller_name.singularize}".to_sym).permit(locality_params)
  end
end
```

2. State controller

```
class StateMastersController < LocalityController
  alias_method :state_master_params, :locality_master_params

  private
  def locality_params
    @locality_params = %i|name code status country_code|
  end
end
```

*Expectation*: country-state-city controllers should be inherited from one controller and manage same templates, methods for all those controllers to DRY.

This code works fine as per the expectation.

**Issue**: after removing below code(as it is unnecessary):

`alias_method :state_master_params, :locality_master_params`

it gives error as:
`ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

I've added `alias_method` to prevent above error.

Getting same error in other controllers too: country-city controllers.

Is there any convention to define method as `state_master_params` for `state_master_controller`?
`